# UITableView background has weird behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`, which is showed from the root view controller. In the simulator everything is working fine, but when testing the app on a real device running iOS7, the background of the UITableView is the same image of the root view. 
Setting both `backgroundColor` and `backgroundView` has no effect. I have also tried to set `tableView.opaque = NO` and setting the background of the cells, but still not results. 

Any ideas on how to fix this behaviour?

Comment: Could you post the code where you're setting the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this piece of code:

```
contentTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
contentTable.delegate = self;
contentTable.dataSource = self;
[contentTable setBackgroundView:nil];
[contentTable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]]; // i.e. Bluecolor as backgrounf
```

This will return a table with a blue background.